# CollectionView lag while scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Sir, I am a beginner. I am unable to understand this. I am facing the lag while scrolling the collectionView. i remove the Cell-shadow then lagging is gone. but i want to add shadow. my cellforItem code is:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellCollection";
        [self.MainCollectionView registerClass:[CVC_ImageWithLabel class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        CVC_ImageWithLabel *customCell = (CVC_ImageWithLabel *)[self.MainCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        //cell text
        customCell.NameLabel.text = [data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //cell image
        customCell.CellImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[image_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        customCell.CellImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

        return customCell;
    }
```

Can you help me sir?
i have tried to add below code but failed to do so.

```
customCell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
customCell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

Comment: add more code in cellForItem

Comment: added full code sir.

Comment: add this viewDidLoad         [self.MainCollectionView registerClass:[CVC_ImageWithLabel class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellCollection"];

Comment: add your shadow code into cell file method layoutSubview()

Comment: I do this in viewWillAppear ... done the same .. but still lagging for shadow

Comment: where did you added shadow code?

Comment: i did this in collectionviewcell.m file. my code is :   
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
        self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should setup one more property of layer - shadowPath:

```
self.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: self.bounds cornerRadius: self.layer.shadowRadius].CGPath;
```

This path defines the outline used to construct the layer's shadow instead of using the layer's composited alpha channel. Specifying the path explicitly using this property will usually improve rendering performance

Comment: YES it improves a bit. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add shadows as images, it's way better for performance. You can use image slicing to help with scaling of images.